# Combining Neo4j and Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j as my primary database. It is a nice piece of graph database that gives me very good control over connections between nodes. However, it seems to lack highly in searching full text (search feature on a website). And therefore, I am thinking of using Elasticsearch for creating search feature on my application. But there are few issues while doing this. Let's say we are searching for user posts. In neo4j posts could have the following model.

```
(post)<-[:AUTHOR]-(user)
(post)-[:LIKED_BY]->(otherusers)
(post)-[:COMMENTED_BY]->(otherusers)
(post)-[:HAS_PHOTO]->(photos)
```

Nice thing about Neo4j (let's say while getting posts in a user profile) is that you can grab all this at once (also profile picture and user details while you're at it and if you have already liked the post). That is a lot of detail in one query (cypher command). Now if we want to give the same level of detail to Elasticsearch output I can think of the following at the moment:

1. Store everything in Neo4j and Elasticsearch. When a text is searched list the results from elasticsearch itself. But there are still problems like getting if the user has already liked the post (this might need querying neo again for each post? this sounds not so nice)
2. Store post id in Elasticsearch. When populating search results, grab information of each post from neo4j database with this post id and display the results. (10 results -> 10 separate calls, sounds very inefficient again)
3. Get a list of ids that the Elasticsearch provides and make 1 call to neo4j and grab results (don't know how to do this or if there are performance issues). A cypher reference could be helpful.

Any solutions apart from these? These sound a little inefficient.

Comment: Hi @pewpewlasers, we just released this : http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/04/20/graph-aided-search-the-rise-of-personalised-content.html

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen Hey thanks for the link, looks like a great project. Will definitely check it out. Any info on performance and scalability?

Comment: Performances are highly dependent of the performance of your cypher queries, reco engine or even the latency between ES and neo4j. it adds of course this latency to the ES query time in total (we measured sometimes 40ms for raw cypher and 10ms when using a java based engine on neo4j side). We have improved this however with the last version of neo4j and the binary protocol instead of http.

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen okay thanks. will definitely check it out.

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen Is there any link for installation guide to integrate neo4j 3.0.1 with elastic search 5.0?

Comment: @SantoshHegde The neo4j replication module is compatible with ES5.0, however the Elasticsearch plugin itself (graph-aided-search) is not yet compatible with ES5.0 (as it will highly be a complete rewrite), we have no ETA when we will release an ES5.0 compatible version for the community.

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen Is there any work-around to use graph-aided-search? Or should i use 2.3 only??

Comment: Graph-aided search is compatible for ES 2.3 and 2.4

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen do you know if the neo4j plugin is compatible with ES 6.x? I didn't find that anywhere in the documentation (that code still is referencing version 2.3)

Comment: Answering my own question. GraphGrid enterprise has integration with with Elastic 6.x and above. Not sure if Graphaware has that or is on the roadmap.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bit of an opinion-based question because it doesn't have a "right" answer, so prepare for the SO no-fun hammer to come crashing down... but I've been thinking that a one-two (Elasticsearch then Neo) punch is the best way to handle this: index properties in Elasticsearch, perform a full-text search to get possible IDs, then build a Cypher match that limits results to returned IDs.

In Cypher, you can use `IN []` to return records that match within an array. So you could do `MATCH (u:Student { age: 30 }) WHERE ID(u) IN [1, 2, 3, 4] RETURN u`. The trick of integrating Elasticsearch with Neo, then, is to make it easy to build Cypher queries around ES results. I don't really have tips on doing that cause it will depend on your language and driver.

In Neo4j.rb, I'm thinking about trying to automate this so you can do this:

```
student.lessons(:l).where(name: 'Chris').to_a
```

...and it'll know that the Lesson model is using Elasticsearch, do the query, and then change the query for the user so it is effectively this:

```
student.lessons(:l).where('ID(l) IN {elasticsearch_results}').params(elasticsearch_results: [1, 2, 3, 4]).to_a`
```

I've been using Searchkick for full-text search with Neo and it's been going well. I think this is doable. Not a solution to your problem but it's how I'm thinking through it, so maybe it'll give you some ideas.

It's worth noting that Neo does have fuzzy search using `=~`, it just doesn't use indexes so there may be a performance hit. This might not be a problem, though, since you can filter the number of nodes and properties Cypher has to inspect by adding more information to other parts your query. You should do some benchmarks with your data to figure out if the added overhead of Elasticsearch and more complicated queries are necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Just a question though, how is the performance of `WHERE ID(u) IN [1, 2, 3, 4] RETURN u`? will it be really slow if there are let's say over 200,000 records and higher (Indexes are in place)? In other words, will this cypher scale well?

Comment: Using IDs is the fastest possible way of loading nodes from the database. I don't know how it works behind the scenes but I'm pretty sure it will immediately filter results using those IDs and then work outwards from there, so it should scale very well. Just use the usual caution when working with IDs.

Comment: Also, one thing I learned recently from a SO comment: A future (the next?) version of neo4j will use indexes for `=~` conditions!

Comment: Beware: IDs are transient.  Do not rely on them unless you are loading them in a transient manner (for instance, return the ID 's from a query, and then use them in a second query).

Answer (score 3):

I am also looking for Neo4J & Elasticsearch integration. I have seen "Neo4j River Plugin for ElasticSearch". But i don't know how to use it. If you guys will find any information about integrating with "Neo4j River Plugin for ElasticSearch", please let me know, will be really helpful.

Comment: I have integrated ES & Neo4J with river plugIn and posted my answer, refer the link below :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323323/examples-about-integration-of-elasticsearch-with-neo4j/28428555#28428555